# Getting HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I have Recorded my PHP/JSON site using JMeter. I tried to run the recorded script and got error message for most of the sampler.

I tried to change the POST URL as `"manufactureradmin/ticketsreportcontroller/getServiceAgency"` it was success but i am getting the wrong Response data.

**Sampler Request**

`Thread Name: Thread Group 1-1
Sample Start: 2017-04-28 01:08:52 IST
Load time: 106
Connect Time: 0
Latency: 106
Size in bytes: 493
Sent bytes:782
Headers size in bytes: 260
Body size in bytes: 233
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""): text
Response code: 400
Response message: Bad Request`

`Response headers:
HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request
Date: Thu, 27 Apr 2017 19:38:52 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.25 (Amazon) PHP/7.0.14
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.0.14
0: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Length: 233
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/json`

`HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType: application/json
DataEncoding: null`

**Request**

`POST http://assist-qa.innothinkglobal.com/api/public/manufactureradmin/ticketsreportcontroller/getServiceAgency`

POST data:

Cookie Data:
`laravel_session=eyJpdiI6IjVjY3lkcmRSME83eGVWRmlCcHIrT2c9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiM3FMeXRSQ1RndzU0ZmRnOFBpd21JN0FONU9TNlE4d1VYcCtoZjJvdGNBWmhoRUNcL2phU0tQR29yZXpKaHFmcDNlYUk0QUM0VlpHT3EyZ2JoeEJiNXB3PT0iLCJtYWMiOiI1ODgyMGEwMTE0ZTYyY2VhMGY4MWM5MDg4MzM3YmNlMzA3Mzc0YzEyNjFkNzUxY2YwNjA1ZGE0OTFhMmYzNmRhIn0%3D`

`Request Headers:
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://assist-qa.innothinkglobal.com/manufactureradmin/
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 0
Host: assist-qa.innothinkglobal.com`

**Response Data**

`{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"The request is missing a required parameter, includes an invalid parameter value, includes a parameter more than once, or is otherwise malformed. Check the \"access token\" parameter."}`

Comment: To your HTTP request, you need to add a token in the request header. E.g. `Authorization` `AccessToken`. To add a header manager: right click on the HTTP request > Add > Config Element > HTTP Header Manager.

Comment: Also, your response is not success. Check this parameter `HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request`

Comment: Already HTTP Header Manager is added below the HTTP request with the below fields                                                                             
 Referer http://assist-qa.innothinkglobal.com/manufactureradmin/
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0
Accept application/json, text/plain, */*
Content-Type application/json

Comment: There is no token in your header manager.

Comment: Added the token in the header getting the same error

Comment: Token might have expired. You need to extract the token in the first step and use it in the subsequent steps.

Comment: This is my login Request data ,POST data:
{"username":"vgstesting53@gmail.com","password":"Test@1234","rememberme":true,"login_type":2,"grant_type":"password","client_id":"a49ded548c4031a6231c129f0e4aaffa","client_secret":"1f9b7f7ddfed339b181b74b5fe87a665"}

Cookie Data:
laravel_session=eyJpdiI6Imd1R25heWswU0lcL2tIWWhmSDVGeXRRPT0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6IkgxbHhCZmlRTHFSY3E0WFRaMmVBYkhJTUt5V1drb

Comment: I dnt find any token for the login page Request Headers:
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://assist-qa.innothinkglobal.com/login
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Content-Type: application/json
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Content-Length: 215
Host: assist-qa.innothinkglobal.com

Comment: You need to add all those details in the header. not in the request. E.g. username value
password value
and so on... Check this https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhdwp.png

Comment: Getting error as Response message: Unauthorized and Response data s {"error":"access_denied","error_description":"The resource owner or authorization server denied the request."}

Comment: Please share the screenshot of your test plan.

Comment: I beleive the issue is with    HTTP Authorization Manager has the below  http://assist-qa.innothinkglobal.com/api/public/manufactureradmin/ticketsreportcontroller/getServiceAgency ${AUTH_LOGIN} ${AUTH_PASSWORD}   KERBEROS  How to configure this in property files

Comment: Your first request response will have the token. You have to share the test plan, else it is difficult to know what is going on. There are many variables to debug your issue.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0ByhrSdpKbX4XUXFaSnNEYjc3UE0?usp=sharing please check the testplan shared

Comment: What is the response of the first request?

Comment: "status":true,"response":{"customerid":"4507b0a0942249bc17ee97a127f0e288","customersecret":"92f8858b0f61b97ce0c62d47cd37ebbc"}}  this the response data for the 1st one

Comment: You need to extract the authorization token and pass it in the next request.

Comment: is there any doc to do that extraction

Comment: @irshadmohammedyakubkhan, you can find great manual here: http://blogs.quovantis.com/jmeter-authorization-with-dynamic-access-token/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OAuth is a basically a way of getting a token. If you're load-testing OAuth-enabled application you need to do the following:

Request temporary access token
Authorize access token
Change temporary access token to something permanent
You can do steps above manually, capture permanent access token via sniffer and add it to your requests as a separate HTTP Request parameter. If you have limited number of user logins to reuse in test it may do the trick for you.

However if you need to test end-to-end flow which assumes obtaining token process via JMeter you need to consider OAuth Sampler Plugin

So basically you need to do one of the following:

Manual 3-stepped OAuth login and capture token process followed by adding token as a parameter of HTTP Requests for each virtual user
Automated OAuth login process by means of JMeter OAuth sampler
If you have limited number of logins/users option 1 may be better

Answer (score 2):

You need to add [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) to your [Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan) and configure it to send [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) with the value of **[application/json](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#MIME_type)**

Looking into your sampler result you are sending request as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and my expectation is that this is the reason your server cannot parse the request properly.

See [Testing SOAP/REST Web Services Using JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/testing-soaprest-web-services-using-jmeter) article for more details on configuring JMeter for sending requests to API endpoints.

Comment: getting error message in response data {"error":"access_denied","error_description":"The resource owner or authorization server denied the request."}

Comment: I am getting this in the browser console will it help to resolve ?oauth
 
 Object { access_token="tBeOvabjZjPWYIYQTsjUiQ9o24IwSTRvzUqdYyQt",  token_type="Bearer",  expires_in=28800,  more...}
access_token
 
 "tBeOvabjZjPWYIYQTsjUiQ9o24IwSTRvzUqdYyQt"
token_type
 
 "Bearer"
expires_in
 
 28800
refresh_token
 
 "miP3bnUQuwKHcs0LovRcj5hjtUtzHlwOTBbHOVk2"

Comment: You are missing one more header with the name of `Authorization` and the value of `Bearer: some_token_here`. You now need to get this token somehow, check out [How to Run Performance Tests on OAuth Secured Apps with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-performance-tests-oauth-secured-apps-jmeter) for possible options.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, there was the same error but when I add Content-Type header inside HTTP header manager it worked.

[image]